# Can't create wifi hotspot with Windows 10

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, hotspot

I have an HP Pro x2 running Windows 10 Enterprise x64. It has a Verizon SIM card and under Settings > Network & Internet > Cellular, it has `Verizon Wireless (LTE)` listed as `Connected`. Under Settings > Network & Internet > Wi-fi, it has the switch set to on.

Under Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Network Connections > Cellular, I've right-clicked and selected Properties > Sharing; there I've checked the box for “Allow other network users to connect through this computer’s internet connection.” In its dropdown, I've selected "Wi-Fi". Current network connection is via the cellular SIM card and it works fine by itself.

Now, under Settings > Network & Internet > Mobile Hotspot, I click to turn on the hotspot, but it switches to off immediately and says:

> We can't set up mobile hotspot. Turn on Wi-Fi.

The cellular network adapter info is as follows:

```
Manufacturer:   HP
Model:  HP lt4211 Gobi 4G Module
Firmware:   T77H468.V.3.2.7.2
Network type:   GSM
```

The SIM card doesn't have a PIN (it's blank). What am I missing? I've updated the driver for the HP Gobi Module from HP. In addition, I've modified the registry with the following changes so it allows me to have access to the hotspot feature:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Network Connections]
"NC_PersonalFirewallConfig"=dword:00000001
"NC_ShowSharedAccessUI"=dword:00000001
"NC_AllowNetBridge_NLA"=dword:00000001
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the OEM Bloatware that handles the WiFI for Windows, if you do, get rid of it then try.

Comment: Thanks, @Ramhound. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you asking how you confirm if your installation has OEM Bloatware on it?

Comment: I guess both: how to confirm and how to get rid of it.

Comment: [how do i uninstall an application in windows](https://www.google.com/#q=how%20do%20i%20uninstall%20an%20application%20in%20windows)

Comment: Would I remove the "Microsoft Wi-Fi"? If so, what do I replace it with?

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise -  is this part of a domain with group policies?

Comment: Yes, @Linef4ult, the machine is part of a domain with group policies. When I'm testing the cellular, I disconnect from the network by removing the cable from the Ethernet port.

Comment: GPs will still override whatever you do. If the company employs a VPN(within machines or from Verizon directly) then they will often disable hotspotting so you dont suddenly have the entire family of an employee running netflix over a confidential company network.

Comment: Is that why it immediately toggles to off when I try to turn hotspots on? But I don't have the network cable attached so I'm not on the company network. Is there a way to verify that it's the GP that's killing me?

Comment: @Alex - Are you connected to a domain?  If you are then contact the Domain Administrator, if you are not, then set the local group policy to allow it specifically.

Comment: Is it possible to disconnect this tablet from the domain and change the group policy?

Comment: Hi @Ramhound. Please see my answer below. Still not sure why the cellular connection gets corrupted, but there's a solution to that.

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/questions/1531998/cant-make-windows-hotspot-using-modem-dongle-which-identifies-as-dial-up-conn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this solution for those who are wondering. First, I have the following in a .reg file (I'm aware that the last modification is not recommended by sys admins):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Network Connections]
"NC_PersonalFirewallConfig"=dword:00000001
"NC_ShowSharedAccessUI"=dword:00000001
"NC_AllowNetBridge_NLA"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"DisableBkGndGroupPolicy"=dword:00000001
```

Then I have these commands in a .bat file:

```
REM ----- Run regedit silently to add the necessary network sharing settings -----
regedit.exe /S NetworkSharingSetup.reg

REM ----- Add the hotspot -----
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=Hotspot1 key=123456

REM ----- Start the hotspot -----
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
REM ----- Show the hotspot details -----
netsh wlan show hostednetwork

timeout -t 10 /nobreak

REM ----- Bounce the Cellular connection -----
netsh interface set interface name="Cellular" admin=disabled
netsh interface set interface name="Cellular" admin=enabled

pause
```

I ran into an issue where, after starting the hostednetwork, my cellular connection kept connecting and immediately disconnecting in an infinite loop. I discovered that if I waited (`timeout`) and bounced the connection, it fixed the issue. Not sure why the cellular connection got into this status or why the wait was required.

After creating this batch file, I create a shortcut to it, then right-click > Properties > Shortcut tab > Advanced > check the box for "Run as administrator". This is required for the lines where we bounce the cellular connection.

One final thing: During this process, the tablet was kept off the organization's domain.