# Can't make Windows hotspot using modem dongle which identifies as "Dial-up" connection

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, hotspot, dial-up, usb-modem

I have a USB dongle (ZTE) which works fine on my Windows 10 laptop. In network settings I can see it is acting as a "Dial-Up" connection.

I want to share this connection so I and my friend can use it on our phones and other laptops since we only have one dongle.

As Dial-Up connections are not shared by default I went into the settings and enabled sharing and chose Wi-Fi from the drop down selection.

But even after sharing the dial-up connection, I still see this same message when I want to turn on the hotspot under `Allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connection`:

> we can't set up mobile hotspot because your pc doesn't have an
>   ethernet wifi or mobile data connection

Comment: If it is shareable at all, then users would be able to see the ZTE dongle separately from Windows.  I have a Huawei stick and that is how it works. It does not show up in Windows sharing.

Comment: What does it mean for it to be sharable? Is that something the dongle would have to implement itself rather than the OS providing it? How/where do I look for it showing up in Windows sharing?

Comment: Look in the ZTE Documentation and see if you can log into it. I log into my own stick with a local web browser 192.x.x.x address and set the sharing properties there. Once active on my computer, other users can use it if they know the password I set up. Since it is not a regular Ethernet connection, this is how you do it. I have used this and tested it on my own device.

Comment: So yours tells Windows that its an Ethernet connection rather than a Dial-up connection like mine does? Also there is no documentation on the stick's USB drive. I've had it for ten years, given by someone working at the phone company, not in a box...

Comment: No, it show up in the Windows 10 Network section as a separate device.  It uses the Ethernet icon just to display but it is not regular Ethernet.

Comment: For mine, in some places it shows what looks like an ethernet plug as an icon, but in others it shows a dialup icon. In my Internet/Ethernet it just shows as "Not connected" but in my Internet/Dial-up it shows as DIGI/Connected. Digi is the provider. This is the best technique I stumbled upon to tell that it identifies as Dial-up.

Comment: "In my Internet/Ethernet it just shows as "Not connected" but in my Internet/Dial-up it shows as DIGI/Connected."

That is similar to what my device does. Can you now log into the device and set up sharing?

Comment: How would I find out the dongle's web address?

Comment: Look in your ZTE Documentation or perhaps their support forums. That is how I did it.

Comment: I have no documentation. Dongle was a gift from friend who worked at the provider about ten years ago without a box. Addresses I'm finding via Google are not working so far but I'll keep trying ... Thanks btw

Comment: A similar problem to mine but possibly not the same: https://superuser.com/questions/1029477/cant-create-wifi-hotspot-with-windows-10